# What is the <%= %> tag in html?

Tags: html

I have the following code from a html page:

```
<div class="bd">
   <h1><%= user.fullname %></h1>
</div>
```

What is the <%= %> tag? Is this standard html? I never encountered it before. (user.fullname is a javascript variable)

Here is the full code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script language="javascript">

        // We use this code for handling unexpected errors.
        // Using alert, we are sure that the user get notified in a Mobile device.
        // We add this code at the begining of the index.html and we use only native javascript functions.
        window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNumber) {
            if (typeof(msg) === "string") {
                var error = msg + "\n\nFile: " + url + "\nLine: " + lineNumber;
                // Ommit cordova and 3rd party libs errors.
                if (url.indexOf("cordova.js") == -1 && url.indexOf("externallib") == -1) {
                    window.alert(error);
                }
            } else {
                var error = msg;
            }

            // This may help debugging if we use logging apps in iOs or Android.
            if(typeof(console) !== "undefined" && typeof(console.log) === "function") {
                console.log(error);
            }

            // Let default error handler run.
            return false;
        };

    </script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="childbrowser.js"></script>
    <script src="webintent.js"></script>
    <script src="PushNotification.js"></script>
    <script src="externallib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="externallib/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="externallib/md5.js"></script>
    <script src="externallib/matchMedia.js"></script>
    <script src="externallib/matchMedia.addListener.js"></script>
    <script src="externallib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="externallib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="externallib/backbone-localstorage.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.panels.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.util.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.lang.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.db.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.tpl.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.cache.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.settings.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.sync.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.emulator.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.rdebugger.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mm.fs.js"></script>
    <script data-main="lib/app.js" src="externallib/require.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        // We should wait to phonegap, if not, we get errors like:
        // http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/04/solving-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-error-in-androidphonegap/
        $(document).bind('deviceready', function() {
            MM.log('Deviceready fired');
            MM.deviceReady = true;
            // Store the device locale for further uses.
            navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
                function (locale) {
                    MM.lang.locale = locale.value;
                    MM.log("Device locale loaded: " + locale.value);
                },
                function () {}
            );
            // Disable the back button, exists the app.
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
                MM.panels.goBack();
            }, false);

            // Call deviceIsReady function in plugins.
            // Plugins may not be able to listen for the deviceready event because it's possible that it was fire
            // when plugins whasn't loaded, we use a timeout of 5 seconds.
            setTimeout(function() {
                for (var el in MM.plugins) {
                    var plugin = MM.plugins[el];

                    if (typeof(plugin.deviceIsReady) == 'function') {
                        plugin.deviceIsReady();
                    }
                }
            }, 5000);
            MM.fs.init();
        });

        // This function is for handling when the app is opened using a custom URL SCHEME.
        function handleOpenURL(url) {
            MM._appLaunchedByURL(url);
        }
    </script>

    <style id="mobilecssurl"></style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="add-site" style="display: none">

</div>

<div id="manage-accounts" style="display: none">

</div>

<div id="main-wrapper" style="display: none; background-color: white">

    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <header class="header-main">
            <nav class="nav-main">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="nav-item home menu-home">
                        <a href="#" class="ir"  id="mainmenu">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <span id="page-title"></span>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div id="panel-left" class="panel user-menu"></div>

    <div id="panel-center" class="panel"></div>

    <div id="panel-right" class="panel"></div>
</div>

<div id="app-dialog">
    <div>
        <div class="modalHeader">
        </div>
        <div class="modalContent">
        </div>
        <div class="modalFooter">
        </div>
        <div class="modalClear"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="menu_template">
<header>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="refresh app-ico">
            <a href="#refresh">
                <img width="16" height="16" src="img/reload.png" border="0">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="<%= MM.util.getMoodleFilePath(user.profileimageurl) %>" border="0">
        </div>
        <div class="bd">
            <h1><%= user.fullname %></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like classic ASP to me

Comment: @John Conde: The tag interprets the javascript variable and outputs  it's value. I don't think asp can do that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML and everything to do with whatever framework you're using.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the `<%= %>` tag in html?

There is none. There are several templating engines that use `<%` and `%>` to delimit either templates or code blocks, though: Active Server Pages (ASP), JavaServer Pages (JSP), probably others. Those usually do server-side processing and replace the text in the `<% ... %>` with whatever should go there.

For instance, in your example

```
<h1><%= user.fullname %></h1>
```

if the `user` object's `fullname` property is `"Joe Bloggs"` when the resource is requested, the engine will swap that in for that token before sending the text, so what the browser actually sees is

```
<h1>Joe Bloggs</h1>
```

In your case, as you point out, the processing is happening client-side. Your `<% ... %>` tokens are within `<script type="text/template">...</script>` blocks, so the `<` isn't at all special. (Before DCoder pointed that out to me, I had a complex explanation here of why it worked...but then, er, DCoder pointed out that they were in `script` blocks, so...)

[DCoder also identified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729083/157247) that these are templates being handled by backbone.js, which reuses underscore.js's templates.

Comment: You made it more sense.+1

Comment: ASP, JSP are all server side templating engines. This seems to be client side (the user.fullname is a javascript variable). How do I find out what templating engine is used? (it's not ASP or JSP)

Comment: @kovacslorand: See the second half of the answer. Re how to tell which one is being used, I don't really see much alternative than to look through the various `.js` files for `<%`. I dare say it's something called by `MM.fs.init`, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the OP is using backbone.js, and they reuse the [templating engine](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/) from [underscore.js](https://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#template).

Comment: @DCoder: Nice one!! +1 to your answer (Kovacs -- that's the one I'd accept). I had glanced at the backbone site because it seemed likely, but didn't spot the templating.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks :) I upvoted your answer because you referenced the standard, but the OP's template is inside a `<script>` tag, and therefore I think [script data state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#script-data-state) is used, not plain data state, so escaping the `<` is not needed. Can you clarify if I'm reading the spec wrongly?

Comment: @DCoder: Nope, I think you're right about this as well!! I just missed the `script` tag.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the `<%= %>` tag in html?

Like [T.J. Crowder said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25728521/1233508), that is not an HTML tag, it comes from a client-side templating engine that happens to use these expressions to indicate the beginning/end of dynamically interpolated content.

> How do I find out what templating engine is used? (it's not ASP or JSP)

Based on the fact that your page loads backbone.js, the template engine is most likely [backbone's template engine](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/), which is actually borrowed from [underscore.js](https://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#template).

Answer (score 0):

That's either ASP.NET or JavaScript markup that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

That's usually a form of server side programming. It could be JSP (in Java), ASP or even PHP (with [asp tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags) enabled). It will replace the contents (at server response time) of the `<%= %>` with the server side variable's value.

Answer (score -1):

The statement '<%= user.fullname %>' evaluates the property 'user.fullname' and renders it as a string.  The 'user' object could exist as a property on the page or could be a static class type.