# What is the difference between <!-- XX--> and <%--XX--%> in asp

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!-- -->
<%-- --%>
```

Both are comment out tags. What is the difference if they appear in the same file?

Update:

Sorry this is actually appeared in a aspx file. So is there any difference there?

Comment: the latter isn't valid HTML... neither is the first, as comments end in a `-->`

Comment: The second is most likely part of a template language.

Comment: Possible duplicate :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728496/what-is-the-tag-in-html/25728521#25728521

Comment: @C-linkNepal `<%=` !== `<%--`

Comment: @epascarello yeah, but question type seems exactly like that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clientside**

```
<!-- Clientside HTML Comment -->
```

View Source and you can see this comment in the code

**Serverside for .NET or other languages that support it**

```
 <%-- Serverside comment--%>
```

View Source and you will not see this comment in the HTML markup

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acf8afk(v=vs.85).aspx) *Server-side comments allow developers to embed code comments in any part of an ASP.NET application file (except for within  code blocks). Any content between opening and closing tags of server-side comment elements, whether ASP.NET code or literal text, will not be processed on the server or rendered to the resulting page.*

Comment: Downvote means "This answer is not useful" not "shame on anyone who answered the question".

Answer (score 1):

The first is actually HTML. The second isn't.

EDIT: (removed as irrelevant, after OP's edit.)

EDIT2: After OP's clarification: ASP.NET will not render the `<%-- ... --%>` comment, and it will not reach the browser. It will render the `<!-- ... -->` comment as it renders any other HTML tag. The browser (or any other user agent that parses HTML) will then ignore the `<!-- ... -->` comment on the clientside. Thus, the former shows up in HTML source (but is ignored thereafter); the latter only shows up in the template, not in HTML (as it is not valid HTML).

Answer (score 0):

1. First one is html comment.
2. Second one `<%-- your comment--%>` jsp  comment.